# how to synchronize data from postgresql to GreenPlum? gpfdist? or gp stream server?

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I want to build an OLTP app.But beacuse of GreenPlum's insert slow and lock,I chose write in postgresql,and read in GreenPlum.
Now,I decided to use *GreenPlum stream server*(build-in gpfdist).

---

**question1**: When the data stream to *GP*,if it will lock the table?

**question2**: Does anyone else have a better idea?

---

**reference1:**
[Fast Data Loading into Greenplum----gpfdist](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/fast-data-loading-greenplum-open-source-warehouse-katta-/)

**reference2:**
[Developing a Greenplum Stream Server Client](https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/6-1/greenplum-stream/api/dev_client.html)

Comment: How big are the tables in Postgres?  Are you planning on archiving data in GP or just keep a copy there?  What are the business requirements for GP (analytics/BI)?

Comment: Sorry for the delay!The tables in Postgres will grow up every day.In the future,I will use `Text Similarity Analytics` in GP.

Comment: Plus，I want to `insert、update` in postgresql,and to `find` in GP.What is said above is my OLTP.

Comment: Loading data will not lock the table for reading.  I would lean towards loading via truncate and then insert with gpfdist on a daily basis.  Use partitions too so that you can prune old data out of Postgres and keep all history in GP.